# Attempted import error: '@module' does not contain a default export (imported as 'module')

Tags: typescript, webpack, build, create-react-app, craco

I'm using craco to create a react app.
Here are my ts configs:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I'm also using a git submodule to import utils from it.

When I run `craco start` everything works fine. But when I run `craco build` I get this error:

```
Attempted import error: '@pinata/sdk' does not contain a default export (imported as 'pinataClient')
```

This is how `pinataClient` is imported:

```
import pinataClient "@pinata/sdk";
```

When I edit this line to

```
const pinataClient = require("@pinata/sdk");
```

Here is the `tsconfig` file of the submodule:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "include": ["./test", "./tasks", "./utils"],
  "files": ["./hardhat.config.ts"]
}
```

I think it is a webpack error, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue and I'm also using craco

Comment: no sorry :( Maybe upvote the post to make it more visible